# Pad nodejs buffer to 32 bytes after creation from string

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

Say I create a buffer from a string:

`let buf =  Buffer.from('a test');`

What is a good way to pad `buf` (with zeros or nulls) to 32 bytes?

Answer (score 3):

I can think of a couple of options:

#### Pad first

You could pad the string **before** using `from`:

```
const buf = Buffer.from(theString.padEnd(32, "\0"));
```

Note that if the string's length is greater than 32, the buffer's will be as well.

If `theString` is `"example"` (for instance), you end up with these bytes in the buffer:

```
65 78 61 6d 70 6c 65 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

#### `alloc` and `copy`

Alternatively, [`alloc`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_static_method_buffer_alloc_size_fill_encoding) and [`copy`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_copy_target_targetstart_sourcestart_sourceend):

```
const buf = Buffer.alloc(32, 0);
Buffer.from(theString).copy(buf);
```

Note that only as many bytes as will fit are copied (it doesn't throw if the string is longer, it just leaves off the end).

Comment: I like this, in case anyone wants to pad from start: `.copy(buf, 32 - theString.length)`

Comment: @atomh33ls - :-) Or even `.copy(buf, buf.length - theString.length)`. Just beware that if `theString.length` is greater than `buf.length` (or `32`), you'll get an error because of the negative starting position. You could use `Math.max` to defend against that: `.copy(buf, Math.max(0, buf.length - theString.length))`. Edge condition, I know. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [Buffer.concat()](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_static_method_buffer_concat_list_totallength) for this purpose:

```
let buf =  Buffer.from('a test');

const totalLength = 32;
const result = Buffer.concat([buf], totalLength);

console.log('Result length:', result.length);
console.log('Result:', result);
```

This will output something like:

> Result length: 32

> Result: <Buffer 61 20 74 65 73 74 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>